# AngularJS route in symfony2 app

Tags: angularjs, symfony, controller, routes, http-status-code-404

I successfully installed angularJS in my symfony app.

When "/" is called my symfony controller matches the route on a specific template. This is the only time a symfony controller action is called.

The entire rest of the application is routed through angularJS - route.

All angularjs specific views are located in

```
web/*
```

When i click a link i.e. "/friends", the proper html-file is loaded.

The url is:

```
http://example.com/friends
```

When i click an other link i.e. "/trash", the proper html-file is loaded too.

The url is:

```
http://example.com/trash
```

But when i reload the page, symfony tries to find a route "/trash" and throughs an error 404.

Is there any way to get around this?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: develop UI as separate project. Doing this you will avoid same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are sending a http request, and symfony2's kernel it processes with Routing, if you see [The Symfony Application Flow](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#the-symfony-application-flow) you can better understand. How to solve this?, I personally use ui-router (the routing framework for AngularJs) with this, your url will be like this: http://example.com/#trash, (with # ), you can see this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router) for more details. If you need more help put the code on github, my user account is ricky6982.

Comment: sorry for late answer, but thanks for answer! great! upvote